# Is that possible to have open dialog window inside child window in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I need to have OpenDialog window being inside browser window of Silverlight application. I am wondering if it possible. Any help is highly appreciated!

Below is the code I have to open child window and OpenDialog:

```
 private void openChildWindow_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Add_ChildWindow ap = new Add_ChildWindow();
        ap.Show();

          OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        // Set filter options and filter index.
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Packages (*.sprj)|*.sprj|Packages (*.sprj)|*.sprj";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        // Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
        bool? userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        // Process input if the user clicked OK.
        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {
            // Open the selected file to read.
            //textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.File.Name;
            System.IO.Stream fileStream = openFileDialog1.File.OpenRead();

            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                // Read the first line from the file and write it the textbox.
               // tbResults.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An Open Dialog window is a system window. Silverlight being sandboxed has to use the system open dialog I believe.

In other words, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Thak you for the tip. I'll keep looking for the answer.